# Serenity Report is not generated Build Failed after successfully running test scenarios in Maven project

Tags: maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Serenity Report is not generated Build failed [image]
Failed to execute goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1:aggregate (serenity-reports) on project digitalContent: Execution serenity-reports of goal net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1:aggregate failed: Plugin net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:3.2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins:serenity-maven-plugin:jar:3.2.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.6.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.6.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:pom:3.6.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.6.3/maven-core-3.6.3.pom: PKIX path building failed: